# Querying Different Categories in Different Loop With Different Offsets

Tags: offsets

I have four loops. In the first loop I want to display all current articles from all categories (breaking news).  In the 2nd loop only articles with the category 4,5,6,7 should be displayed.  But if in the 1st loop an article from these categories were published, this newest article should not appear in the 2nd loop. I would be very grateful about helpful tips and code snippets.[image: Maybe my problem will be better understood by this picture.]

Comment: have a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Loop_Examples_2

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also had your approach in mind at first. The only problem is, if I publish an article with a different category ID in the 1st loop (e.g. 24) then the posts do not slide into the second loop. They remain excluded. Do you know what I mean. I think I need to somehow compare the post IDs. I need to determine the post ID in the first loop and run a query with the second loop. If the post ID is equal, the item may not appear in the second loop, if it is not equal, it may appear in the second loop, as long as it is allowed to appear there after the category ID.

Comment: I have the solution:   

`<h2>Loop n°1</h2>
<?php
$ids = array();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_title();
?>
<?php $ids[]= $post->ID;
endwhile; ?>
 
<h2>Loop n°2</h2>
<?php
query_posts("showposts=50");
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if (!in_array($post->ID, $ids)) {
  the_title();?>
<?php }
endwhile; ?>`

from here: [link] (https://www.isitwp.com/avoid-duplicate-posts-in-multiple-loops/)

Comment: What is the result of your code solution? In the suggested link, I was particular referring to the code ideas in 'Multiple Loops in Action' and further 'Note for Multiple Posts in the First Category'. also, for reasons discussed here in the forum, please do not use `query_posts` to code custom loops; https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts